# Why is micelle formation endothermic?

Tags: colloids

Most websites mention that it is endothermic and some mention that it is endothermic at low temp. and exothermic at high temp. Nor do I know the correct answer neither I can guess the reason for any of them. An explanation would be a great help.

Comment: Some references and quotes would help to attract good answers. // Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to prevent misunderstanding,  need of clarification, objections, downvoting or closure.

Comment: Also, micelle formation starting from what? From monomers in solution? Write the full equation to which you are referring.

Comment: Do you mean enthalpy? The enthalpy of micelle formation (say SDS in water)  is normally small, the main effect is a huge entropy increase ($\sim 140$ J/K/mol) making $\Delta G$ negative. The enthalpy change is a mix of negative change moving the tails from water and a positive term of repulsion between charge on head groups.